# How can I create an android app from pwa?

Tags: progressive-web-apps

I am trying to make a pwa. I am actually new on that topic. I saw some pwa are automatically generating an apk application on device.Example: https://polytimer.rocks/
when I add it to home screen. It automatically create a apk application. igenapp are also doing same thing. So why my pwa is not making any apk but their one doing.

Comment: The webApk installed for a valid PWA is not the same as a true app. You can learn some more here. https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/integration/webapks

Comment: Does your PWA when running with an HTTPS URL pass as a valid PWA with the Chrome Lighthouse tool? If there are issues, it usually gives good hints.